# My Vim plugins (installed with Vundle) aren’t loading

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle

I'm trying to install the vim-scala and vim-sensible plugins using Vundle. I followed the directions here: https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim

In my `~/.vim` directory I have: a folder named 'bundle' with a Vundle.vim directory I downloaded from the tutorial.

In my `~/.vimrc` I have:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plugin 'derekwyatt/vim-scala'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Then I open Vim, type

```
:PluginInstall
```

and my plugins are shown to be successfully installed. However, when I open Vim again, nothing changes.

**Edit:** I should note that I had the same problems using Pathogen, so I don't think this is a bug in Vundle.

**Edit:** My `.vim` and `.vimrc` are in `/root/.vim`; I am running on Linux.

Comment: Do you have `set nocompatible` and `filetype off` at the start? That's required too. Other than that, open up an issue at github with roughly this content if you think this is a bug.

Comment: @Cubic, I apologize, I do have those. Edited my post.

Comment: Just to check: Your plugins actually end up in '~/.vim/bundle'? I'm assuming you run on linux or osx?

Comment: Correct, after the installation, the plugins are seen in ~/.vim/bundle. I am running on 14.04 Linux

Comment: What is the output of "set rtp" (it will print your runtimepath, and it should include entries like "~/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible/..." and so on.

Comment: How do you check if your plugins are actually working? Technically your could run vim-sensible without noticing.

Comment: @Josh: output of "set rtp" is runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim,~/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible,~/.vim/bundle/vim-scala,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/shar
e/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after,~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.
vim,~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/after,~/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible/after,~/.vim/bundle/vim-scala/after

Comment: @Cubic: That is true, I just assumed something would give it away.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything wrong here. Check if tab completion works (:e <TAB> and you should see a list of possible filename completions).

Comment: Alternatively, try :SortScalaImports in a Scala file (it's a command exported by vim-scala; if it works your plugins are loading fine).

Comment: When you run Vim to test if things are corrctly installed, do you do it as root or as a regular user? Could you paste somewhere the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: I am running as root. The out of :scriptnames gives me a lot of files related ot my plugins. It looks like you guys are right, I just didn't notice the plugins were loaded. Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Either delete the question if you don't believe this will be useful to other people or write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the asker [jeffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649452/jeffrey), he resolved his problem. His plugins were loading, but he just did not realize it, because the plugins were not changing any obvious, visible Vim settings.